# Validation rule for Multi Select Picklist for duplicate values

Tags: apex, validation-rule

I am trying to add a validation rule on a picklist. Values in Picklist1 should not be same as Picklist2 & Picklist3
Values in all 3 picklist are same,, But user should be able select "XXX" value in any one of them. If user select same value in 2 or more picklist it should give error.

Any help ??

Comment: Hey guys,
What I was trying to achieve is "Standard object's page have 3 Multi-select picklist lets say MultiSelectPicklist_A,MultiSelectPicklist_B & MultiSelectPicklist_C. All 3 multi-select picklists having same data. lets assume all are having value as 1,2,3,4. Now I wanna have a validation rule in order to avoid having same data in any of two or more picklists. Lets say user have selected value 1 in MultiSelectPicklist_A then if user selects value 1 in MultiSelectPicklist_B AND/OR MultiSelectPicklist_C then error should be thrown"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please disregard my previous answer, as you can only use string literals, not variables in this. 
You might use IF(TEXT(FieldAPI_name)=TEXT(field2API_Name), true, false)

Comment: Hey,, Thanks for quick reply,,
But it gives error says "Field xxxxx is a multi-select picklist field. Multi-select picklist fields are only supported in certain functions".

Comment: I hate multi-picklists :P 
Then you are probaly going to have to use a before insert/before update trigger.
I believe that a multi-select picklist value is stored like so: value1,value2,...
so you can use String.split to get all the separate string values.
You can then use something like this:
String[] all1 = String.split( obj.field );
String[] all2 = String.split(obj.field2);
boolean isTheSame = false;
for ( String val : all1 )
 for ( String val2 : all2 )
    for ( string val3: all3 )
        if ( val3== va2 ||val2 ==val1 || val3 = val1 )
    {        isTheSame = True;break;
}

Comment: and if isTheSame  = true, give an error and dont update the record.

Comment: haha,, 
I guess triggers are best possible solution here. Your logic is perfect, but just wanna add one point. Mulit-select picklist stroes the value with val1;va2;val3...... 
Thanks for your help..